# How can I get a list of all the active kernel drivers on my Android system?

Tags: android, kernel, device-driver

How can I get a list of all the active kernel drivers on my Android system?.  What is the equivelant of Linux "lsmod" in Android?  I used adb shell and also opened my Android Terminal emulator app and did an "lsmod".  I get some kind of a lame list of two items from my BSP.  But it doesn't list all the drivers on my entire system that the Linux kernel has actively running.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doing an `ls /sys/module/` on my Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.1.1 Jelly bean, I get the following output

http://pastebin.com/2zF8RwvS

That is a list of all the built-in modules in my Kernel 3.0.31

Additionally, there are loadable modules, `ls /system/lib/modules/`

http://pastebin.com/G5KLC65V

Comment: `/system/lib/modules/` did not exist but I found loadable modules in `/lib/modules/`

Answer (score 5):

lsmod will not list all the active drivers in the kernel. lsmod is to list the kernel modules that are inserted now, they can be drivers or some other features. Basically, on embedded systems most of the drivers will not be built as modules, instead they are statically built into the kernel. To get to know all the drivers, you need to go through the /sys directory.

Comment: OK, is the sys directory a list of all the statically linked drivers?  How can I know which are actually being used, i.e. have found their HW and are driving that HW?