# Getting a list of active drivers on Android

Tags: android, linux, drivers

Is there a straightforward way of getting a list of drivers that are currently being used on an Android device? `lsmod` lists a small number of drivers (3), but I'm guessing that most of the drivers are compiled into the kernel rather than as modules.

Obviously, things like `make menuconfig` have no chance of working due to the lack of a development tools on the device itself. I *could* download the kernel sources, but I'm hoping to avoid installing a whole cross-compilation toolchain simply to satisfy my curiosity.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901631/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-active-kernel-drivers-on-my-android-system), but it doesn't really answer my question apart from pointing out *why* `lsmod` won't work in this case.

Comment: What about `sysfs`?  `/sys/module` may contain built-ins.

Comment: @BrianCain: That worked! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/proc/config.gz` should tell you the same information that you would find out in `make menuconfig`.

```
adb pull /proc/config.gz .
zcat /proc/config.gz | less
```

EDIT: Also consider browsing `sysfs` for the built-ins:

```
ls -l /sys/module
```

Comment: I was hoping for something using the `proc` filesystem, but sadly, this file doesn't appear to exist on my device (Samsung Galaxy Note). +1 anyway as this may be useful in the future.