# How can i get the list of all initialized device drivers in a running Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

How can i get the list of all initialized device drivers in a running Linux kernel?

Note that device driver is not the same as module.

There is a related question: [How can I get a list of all the active kernel drivers on my Android system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901631/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-active-kernel-drivers-on-my-android-system)

Comment: what about Lsmod -k   ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

each device driver is attached to some bus, and each bus has a "drivers" directory in sysfs, so something like the following shell command would print each bus and its registered drivers

```
cd /sys/bus; for bus in $(ls); do echo $bus; ls -1 $bus/drivers; echo; done
```

sample output:

```
scsi
sd
sr

sdio

serio
atkbd
psmouse
serio_raw
```

Comment: i like the answer, I'll need to check its validity... Can you perhaps include output of your command for your system? Just for the sake of comparison...